# Windows Server DNS, create CNAME for DNS ZONE www.bing.com

Tags: windows, dns-zone, cname-record, windows-dns

I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/copilot/manage#require-commercial-data-protection-in-) which states:

> Prevent use of Copilot without commercial data protection: Update your
> DNS configuration by setting the DNS entry for [www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com) to be a
> CNAME for nochat.bing.com

In Window Server 2022 DNS, I created a forward lookup zone for `www.bing.com`. When I attempt to create a CNAME record for this zone, the following error is displayed:

[image: Creating CNAME record for www.bing.com zone]

[image: Error: A new record cannot be created. An alias (CNAME) cannot be added to this DNS name. The DNS name contains records that are incompatible with the CNAME record.]

I can create a forward lookup zone for `bing.com`, and create a specific CNAME for `www.bing.com`, but that means I take over address resolution responsibility the `bing.com` zone and I don't want to do that.

How do I follow this Microsoft guidance with Windows Server providing DNS?

Comment: https://www.isc.org/blogs/cname-at-the-apex-of-a-zone/

Comment: Microsoft should not have made this recommendation. You can sense by the way it is written that they knew it was the wrong way. A more current discussion of the inferior nature of this recommendation is here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/copilot-formerly-bing-chat/how-to-block-bing-chat-public-for-organization-users-and/m-p/3925073

Comment: So basically some regards in the thread I just linked are creating a "forwarder" for bing.com zone, which is probably a Linux box running Dnsmasq or something similarly kludgy.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. I've concluded that the CNAME approach is not really viable. Since we are already doing TLS inspection of outbound traffic on our firewall, the header approach works well. I really don't know why anyone would want to implement the CNAME approach as it requires a secondary DNS server.

Comment: A CNAME record, like any other types, resides in a zone that you own. It will be resolved as cname.yourDomainName.com. You can't add a fqdn such as "www.bing.com" as CNAME. Also don't create a zone on your DNS server that you are not responsible for. If you create a forward lookup zone "bing.com", you will not be able to resolve any record in "bing.com" unless you manually add that record in the zone that you created. It won't forward queries to their rightful name servers as you are now responsible for it (from perspective of your DNS clients)